# How to access Preference object of specific fragment from OnSharedPreferenceListener?

Tags: android, fragment, android-preferences

I have a bunch of PreferenceFragments which load their resources from XML files.

Some settings in this Fragments should be inaccessible in some cases.

When I had everything in one Fragment, it was fine. However, when I split it into different Fragments, it became problem.

I have some fields which refers to preferences in specific Fragment. For example:

```
public class GeneralPrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    public Preference mExpandDockPreference;
    public Preference mDefaultPagePreference;
    public Preference mDockModePreference;

    public static GeneralPrefFragment fragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.general_settings);



        fragment=this;
        Debug.d("Assigning fragment");
        if(fragment==null) {
            Debug.d("Fragment is null");
        }
        mExpandDockPreference=findPreference("dockStateDefault");
        mDefaultPagePreference=findPreference("defaultPage");
        mDockModePreference=findPreference("dockMode");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I save the static reference to instance of fragment on creation, and in my OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener I refer to specific field like GeneralPrefFragment.fragment.mDockModePreference. I understand that it is the wrong way, and probably is the reason why my Listener does nothing or crashes with NPE. 
But what is the right way? How can I access specific Preference inside FragmentPreference to disable it?

Or I can use findPreference in OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, and it will return right Preference regardless of the Fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no such method(other than manually create Activity with Fragments, and handle saving preferences...meh).

I, however, solved this in a different way:

1. In onResume() method of each fragment I get an instance of default SharedPreferences. Then I check the preferences which affect availability of my settings items and disable them/enable them accordingly.
2. I create OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener for every PreferenceFragment. So, if there are changes which should be visible immediately to user in the same fragment, the listener does the job. Otherwise, availability is regulated by onResume() method of other fragment.